# change samba server's password through php script

Tags: php, samba

My team leader asked me to make an application through which user can change the samba server's account's password through php script.

Pls tell me how can i implement this one.

I was using the below command in my php script to change the password of linux pc through php script.

exec("echo $newpass | sudo -u root passwd --stdin $username 2>&1");

thanks !!

Comment: Oftopic: hope you properly guard this script against unauthorized abuse. `exec` and `sudo` with password from `php` sounds like a huge security vulnerability to me ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
    $comando="printf \"$passwordViejo\n$passwordNuevo\n$passwordNuevo\n\" | sudo -u $user bash -c \"/usr/bin/smbpasswd -s\"";


    exec($comando, $salida, $estado);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: [Change Linux or UNIX system password using PHP script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-linux-or-unix-system-password-using-php-script.html)

I haven't tested yet.